# Configurable product price stays on $0 after choosing option

Tags: magento-1.9

When I choose an option at a configurable product on our webshop. The price stays on $0 while clearly the associated simple products have amounts. Anyone know what might be the problem?

- Running Magento CE 1.9.2.4
- Using SCP (from github abcfyk updated for 1.9.2.4)
- Disabled 3rd party modules
- Flushed cache
- Reindexed everything
- I've also tried to put configurable product as the same price like the cheapeast associated product. But then it keeps showing the cheapest price.

For example:

- Configurable product: €46.24 [shows on front-end]
- Associated product 1: €46.24
- Associated product 2: €83.96 [choosing this one, keeps €46.24 showing]

Adding associated product 2 to cart, takes price of the main product instead of product 2.

Comment: what price you gave for configurable product ?

Comment: I tried for example $48 (where associated product 1 is: $48 and 2: $57) ; but also tried $0 (as im going to use an updated version of SCP, but not yet until this works); Both ways doesn't work.

Comment: @Sebastiaan Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you set your configurable product price as $0 and hence you are getting this result.

It is better to set the base price for configurable product based on the simple product which cultivates configurable product and the difference in price (for simple products) in the super attribute section.

In case of configurable product, Magento is not looking on the simple product price but for the price configuration that you have within configurable product itself. Please keep that in mind.

### EDIT

This is how you need to configure this in backend

[image]

Here I assume, you set the price of configurable product as `€46.24`. Your first associated products has no price difference and hence no price difference specified (see screen-shot). However the price difference in the second associated product (ie `€83.96 - €46.24 = €37.72`) is specified in the price section of second option (see screen-shot).

ie For configurable product, price of associated products is calculated based on the price configuration in the `associated products` tab, which do not depend upon the price that you set for the real associated simple product !

Comment: Updated post. Tried this already.

Comment: @Sebastiaan please see my edit.

Comment: I forgot to mention that since i have almost 5k products i'm using SCP  (from github abcfyk updated for 1.9.2.4) which takes the pricing automatically from the associated simple products. It does work at the other webshop, but here the price doesn't change.

Comment: @Sebastiaan Then you have to contact that extension developers and query about this.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/291238/57334

Answer (score 1):

By default the price of simple product is not used at all when purchasing a configurable product. The price is calculated purely based on the configurable price and any price adjustments for configurable options. These adjustments are set via the "Associated Products" tab of a configurable product.

Comment: Updated post. Tried this already.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point. You say you set the configurable to the same price as the cheapest and that it keeps showing the cheapest. This is what it's supposed to do as that's the price of the configurable. It *does not* use the price of the simple.

Comment: When I choose an associated product, which has a higher pirce, the price won't change.

Comment: @PeterO'Callaghan Can i get help regard configurable product price issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/291238/57334